# Applying blurring algorithm multiple times

Tags: c, algorithm

I implemented a blurring algorithm and it works. The result is a blurred image but if a pass multiple times the algorithm to my image the image remains unchanged. It's like the extra (more than 1) passings are not having any effect.

```
for (f=0; f<100; f++) {
    for (y = 0; y < image->h; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < image->w; x++) {
            int SUM = 0;



            imageBlur->pixels[y * imageBlur->w + x] = SUM / 9;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if f is 1 or 500 it's still the same result as one pass blur.

Comment: Take a very small image, and then step through the code line by line in a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: This hardly seems surprising since your blurred pixel value appears to be an average of the same 9 surrounding pixel values every time.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes the algorithm does that sums the surrounding pixels and average the value to the center. On every pass the average should be different.

Comment: I see GavinBrelstaff has spotted the error.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It was a minor mistake but I'm wondering that since the pixel i'm processing changes doesn't that affect its neighbors as it will become a surrounding pixel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each pass you are reading the same `image` again without having replaced it with the blurred one: `imageBlur`
You need to do the assignment somehow - some thing like

```
image->pixels[y * imageBlur->w + x] = SUM / 9;
```

Comment: Since the pixel i'm processing changes doesn't that  affect its neighbors as it will become a surrounding pixel???

Comment: well you could just compute a new image imageBlur each time and then before going on to the next pass assign the image values with those from the blurred one. That way you won't get pixel values changing while you are doing the current pass.  Of course that needs twice as much memory,

Comment: I did just that but i think the issue i'm describing is different. `image = imageBlur;` The pixel at (1,1) is the one being rewritten with the new value of average but when pixel (1,2) becomes the one at (1,1) its neighbor (0,1) which was the blurred (1,1) pixel is not the original pixel. Its value is different.

Comment: Since you are only assigning pixels inside a 1 pixel border of the image frame you will, in fact, need to pad the values around the border - that way the input and output images have the same height and width. Best to use the value of the original image around the edge,

Comment: The frame is getting darker with each passing of the algorithm and the image is the same size as the original. One way is in fact to ignore the 1-pixel frame but that's just how the algorithm works. What about the processed pixels that become the neighbors of other to-be processed pixels. Doesn't that affect the pixel that is going to be processed? And I'm not talking just about the border pixels.

Comment: Then again I'm always reading from the old unprocessed image and saving to the new. Ok I got it!

Comment: @G90 yes, if you overwrite the pixels as you process them this will have an effect on pixels you haven't processed yet. I'd ping-pong between two different images. As for the edges, you'll need special-case code of some kind for those. I'd search on techniques for handling that, since there are more than one.

Comment: @MarkRansom At the moment I'm reading from `image` and save each processed pixel at `imageBlu`r and at the end if i want to blur again I save `imageblur` to `image`. That way I always have the original pixels to process. As for the edges I don't mind.